# Proof that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H \cap K|$ for $H,K,HK$ subgroups of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I've found this problem in a book and devised my own proof.
(took me like 5 hours and it seems trivial - just build a bijection).
I am not sure that I haven't made any errors though.
Perhaps some other proof would be simpler.

**Statement:**

$G$ is a group and $H,K,HK \subseteq G$

Prove that $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$

**Proof:**

The statement above is equivalent to:
$\frac{|HK|}{|K|}=\frac{|H|}{|H \cap K|}$

So now we look at the cosets of $K$ in $HK$ - ie. the elements of $HK/K$.
They are exactly $\frac{|HK|}{|K|}$ because of Lagrange's theorem.
Then we look at the cosets of $H \cap K$ in $H$ - ie. the elements of $H/H \cap K$.
They are exactly $\frac{|H|}{|H \cap K|}$ because of Lagrange's theorem.

So if we could find a bijection from $HK/K$ to $H/H \cap K$, we are done.

So let's look at the elements of $HK/K$, they are cosets of the form: $h_1k_1K$,
but $k_1K=K$, so we get $h_1K$.

Then lets look at the elements of $H/H \cap K$,
they are cosets of the form: $h_1H \cap K$.

So let's define $f: HK/K \to H/H \cap K$, $f(hK)=hH \cap K$.

To see that it's a function we need to show that it's well defined.

Let $h_1K=h_2K$, ie. $h_2^{-1}h_1 \in K$ which also implies  $h_2^{-1}h_1 \in H \cap K$

Then we need to show that $f(h_1K)=f(h_2K)$.

So $f(h_1K)=h_1H \cap K$ and $f(h_2K)=h_2H \cap K$

To prove that $h_1H \cap K = h_2H \cap K$
we need $h_2^{-1}h_1 \in H \cap K$.

But we've already shown that.

Hence f is well defined.

Now we need to show that it's injective.

Suppose $f(h_1K)=f(h_2K)$, but $h1K \neq h2K$.

Ie. $h_1H \cap K = h_2H \cap K$ but $h_1K \neq h_2K$.

$h_1K \neq h_2K$ implies $h_2^{-1}h_1 \notin K$ which implies $h_2^{-1}h_1 \notin H \cap K$.

Hence $h_1H \cap K \neq h_2H \cap K$.

So we know f is injective.

Now to check for surjectivity:

Since $H/H \cap K$ has elements of the form $h_1H \cap K$, for each of them we have,
$f(h_1K)=h_1H \cap K$.

QED

Comment: Use `$h_2$` for $h_2$.

Comment: You can't quite use Lagrange's theorem on $HK/K$, because $HK$ isn't necessarily a group. (You can repeat the argument in the proof of Lagrange's theorem and check that it still works here - essentially, showing that $HK$ is a union of $|HK|/|K|$ cosets of $K$ in $G$ - but that's an extra step.)

Comment: I wrote in the title that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Yes, I know that generally $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$. So you're saying this statement is true, even if $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: By the way, do I need $HK$, to be finite? Ie. it feels like I am not using that in my proof?

Comment: The statement is still true if $HK$ is not a subgroup. If $H$ or $K$ is infinite, then $HK$ is also infinite (because it contains both $H$ and $K$), and then you have $\infty = \infty$, so there's nothing to prove; if $H$ and $K$ are both finite, then $HK$ is also finite.

Comment: Well, if they are inf, we could talk about cardinality which is essentially building a bijection, which I've done. Anyway, how are you sure that $HK$ does not have to be a subgroup?

Comment: JCAA's proof works whether or not it's a subgroup (so does yours, except for the Lagrange's theorem statement).

Answer (score 5):

The best and standard way to prove it is to consider the map from $H\times K$ to $HK$ which sends $(h,k)$ to $hk$ and look at the equivalence classes of pairs mapped to the same element of $HK$. That is for every $(h,k)$ count pairs $(h',k')$ such that $hk=h'k'$.

**Edit** To make it complete, $hk=h'k'$ is equivalent to $h^{-1}h'=k'k^{-1}$. The LHS is in $H$, the RHS is in $K$, so both are in $K\cap H$. So the number of pairs $(h',k')$ such that $hk=h'k'$ is the same as the number of elements in $h(H\cap K)$ which is $|H\cap K|$.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence relation $(h,k)\sim (h',k')\stackrel{(def.)}{\iff} hk=h'k'$ induces a partition of $H\times K$ into equivalence classes each of cardinality $|H\cap K|$, and the quotient set $(H\times K)/\sim$ has cardinality $|HK|$. Therefore, if $H$ and $K$ are finite (in particular if they are subgroups of a finite group), we get: $|H\times K|=|H||K|=|H\cap K| |HK|$, whence the formula in the OP. Hereafter the details.

(The formula holds irrespective of $HK$ being a subgroup.)

---

Let's define in $H\times K$ the equivalence relation: $(h,k)\sim (h',k')\stackrel{(def.)}{\iff} hk=h'k'$. The equivalence class of $(h,k)$ is given by:

$$[(h,k)]_\sim=\{(h',k')\in H\times K\mid h'k'=hk\} \tag 1$$

Now define the following map from any equivalence class:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  f_{(h,k)}:[(h,k)]_\sim &\longrightarrow&  H\cap K \\
  (h',k')&\longmapsto& f_{(h,k)}((h',k')):=k'k^{-1} \\
\tag 2
 \end{alignat*}

Note that $k'k^{-1}\in K$ by closure of $K$, and $k'k^{-1}\in H$ because $k'k^{-1}=h'^{-1}h$ (being $(h',k')\in [(h,k)]_\sim$) and by closure of $H$. Therefore, indeed $k'k^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

**Lemma 1**. $f_{(h,k)}$ is bijective.

*Proof*.

\begin{alignat}{2}
f_{(h,k)}((h',k'))=f_{(h,k)}((h'',k'')) &\space\space\space\Longrightarrow &&k'k^{-1}=k''k^{-1} \\
&\space\space\space\Longrightarrow &&k'=k'' \\
&\stackrel{h'k'=h''k''}{\Longrightarrow} &&h'=h'' \\
&\space\space\space\Longrightarrow &&(h',k')=(h'',k'') \\
\end{alignat}

and the map is injective. Then, for every $a\in H\cap K$, we  get $ak\in K$ and $a=f_{(h,k)}((h',ak))$, and the map is surjective. $\space\space\Box$

Now define the following map from the quotient set:

\begin{alignat}{1}
  f:(H\times K)/\sim &\longrightarrow&  HK \\
  [(h,k)]_\sim &\longmapsto& f([(h,k)]_\sim):=hk \\
\tag 3
 \end{alignat}

**Lemma 2**. $f$ is well-defined and bijective.

*Proof*.

- Good definition: $(h',k')\in [(h,k)]_\sim \Rightarrow f([(h',k')]_\sim)=h'k'=hk=f([(h,k)]_\sim)$;
- Injectivity: $f([(h',k')]_\sim)=f([(h,k)]_\sim) \Rightarrow h'k'=hk \Rightarrow (h',k')\in [(h,k)]_\sim \Rightarrow [(h',k')]_\sim=[(h,k)]_\sim$;
- Surjectivity: for every $ab\in HK$ , we get $ab=f([(a,b)]_\sim)$. $\space\space\Box$

Finally, the formula holds irrespective of $HK$ being a subgroup, which was never used in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite easy way to prove this problem. If you understand chinese, there is a classic proof on Yang Zixu's 'Abstract Algebra'. Here is the proof:

Since $H\cap K\le H$, let $|H|/|H\cap K|=m$ and
$H = h_1(H\cap K)\cup h_2(H\cap K)\cup \cdots \cup h_m(H\cap K),$
here $h_i\in H, h_i^{-1} h_j \notin K,i\neq j.$
Clearly,
$HK=h_1K\cup h_2K\cup\cdots\cup h_m K,$
while
$h_iK\cap h_jK = \varnothing,i\neq j,$
thus
$|HK|=m|K|,$
which means
$|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|.$
QED

It is an application of coset decomposition theory. There is no need of considering the bijection or maps etc.

Comment: Why $HK= h_1K\cup...$ etc.?

Comment: Since $H$ is some union of $h_i (H\cap K)$,$HK$ is the sets of all $h_i \in H$ left times $k_j\in K$, thus it is the union of $h_i K$

Comment: This proof only satisfies the case that $H,K$ are finite groups.

Comment: So you "mimic Lagrange's" even in the case $HK$ not a subgroup of $G$, nice. +1

Comment: Interesting. Also it seems I have to mimic Lagrange too in my proof, if HK is not a subgroup of G as another poster has noted in his comments.

Answer (score -1):

In the case that$H\triangleleft G$, this follows immediately from the second isomorphism theorem.

But, actually your result is well known, and called the *product formula*.  Neither $H$ nor $K$ is required to be normal.  See "Product of group subsets - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets

Comment: Isn't it needed for H to be normal? Hm, I know that $HK=KH$ is equiv to $HK$ being a group. Btw a comment above said that $HK$ doesn't have to be a group for this statement to be true.

Comment: But do we need $HK$ to be a group for the statement to be true? A comment above is saying that we don't.

Comment: That I would have to think about.

Comment: Neither $H$ nor $K$ needs to be normal for $HK$ to be a subgroup.  For example in a solvable group products of Sylow subgroups can be a subgroup (a Hall subgroup) even if the Sylow subgroups are not normal. This can be seen in $S_4$. It has a Sylow 2-subgroup $H$ of order $8$ (three of them, none of them normal) and $4$ subgroups $K$ of order $3$ (none of them normal), but $HK$ contains $8\cdot 3=24$ elements so $HK$ is a subgroup, in fact equal to $S_4$.

Comment: @JCAA you're correct. So this is more general than the Second Isomorphism Theorem, meaning you need other things to happen for it to be not just a bijection but a morphism.

Comment: It is not more general because it does not imply the theorem. But it implies an important corollary of the theorem that $HN/N$ has the same number of elements as $H/(H\cap N)$.